# Supprt Vector Machine works in matlab, doesn't work in c++

Tags: c++, matlab, machine-learning, svm

I'm writing an application that uses an SVM to do classification on some images (specifically [these](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/html-files/archive.html)). My Matlab implementation works really well. Using a SIFT bag-of-words approach, I'm able to get near 100% accuracy with a linear kernel.

I need to implement this in C++ for speed/portability reasons, and so I've tried using both [libsvm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) and [dlib](http://dlib.net/ml.html). I've tried multiple SVM types (c_svm, nu_svm, one_class) and multiple kernels (linear, polynomial, rbf). The best I've been able to achieve is around 50% accuracy - even on the same samples that I've trained on. I've confirmed that my feature generators are working, because when I export my c++-generated features to Matlab and train on those, I'm able to get near-perfect results again.

Is there something magical about Matlab's SVM implementation? Are there any common pitfalls or areas that I might look into that would explain the behavior I'm seeing? I know this is a little vague, but part of the problem is that I don't know where to go. Please let me know in the comments if there is other info I can provide that would be helpful.

Comment: Perhaps you should tell that SVM == Support Vector Machines...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing magical about the Matlab version of the libraries, other that it runs in Matlab which makes it harder to shoot yourself on the foot.

A check list:

1. Are you normalizing your data, making all values lie between 0 and 1
   (or between -1 and 1), either linearly or using the mean and the
   standard deviation?
2. Are you parameter searching for a good value of C (or C and gamma in
   the case of an RBF kernel)? Doing cross validation or on a hold out set?
3. Are you sure that your're handling NaN, and all other floating point
   nastiness? Matlab is very good at hiding this from you, C++ not so
   much.
4. Could it be that you're loading your data incorrectly, reading a
   "%s"  into a double or something that is adding noise to your input
   data?
5. Could it be that libsvm/dlib expects the data in row major order and
   your're sending it in in column major (or the other way around)? Again Matlab makes this almost impossible, C++ not so much.
6. 32-64 bit nastiness one version of the library, executable compiled
   with the other?

Some other things:

1. Could it be that in Matlab you're somehow leaking the class (y) into
   the preprocessing? no one does this on purpose, but I've seen it happen.
   If you make almost any f(y) a feature, you'll get almost 100%
   everytime.
2. Sometimes it helps to verify that everything is numerically
   identical by printing to file before training both in C++ and
   Matlab.

Comment: 1. I've tried both normalized and unnormalized data.
2. I've tried parameter searching with almost no success.
3. There are no NaNs in the data. We're simply taking histograms and initializing all values to zero, then dividing by the max count. Since none of the feature vectors are empty these are guaranteed to be positive.
4. I'm fairly certain that's not it. I've tried printing out the vectors passed to the SVM and they look fine.
5. This is possible...I'll look into it.
6. I haven't thought to try this out on 32-bit. I'll give it a shot.

The other two items don't appear to be issues either

Comment: I finally got things working reasonably with OpenCV's CvSvm::train_auto method. It looks like my parameter selections were off.

Answer (score 1):

i'm very happy with libsvm using the rbf kernel. carlosdc pointed out the most common errors in the correct order :-). for libsvm - did you use the python tools shipped with libsvm? if not i recommend to do so. write your feature vectors to a file (from matlab and/or c++) and do a metatraining for the rbf kernel with easy.py. you get the parameters and a prediction for the generated model. if this prediction is ok continue with c++. from training you also get a scaled feature file (min/max transformed to -1.0/1.0 for every feature). compare these to your c++ implementation as well.

some libsvm issues: a nasty habit is (if i remember correctly) that values scaling to 0 (zero) are omitted in the scaled file. in grid.py is a parameter "nr_local_worker" which is defining the mumber of threads. you might wish to increase it.