# svm - confused at the result and scores is much greater than +1 or -1

Tags: svm, text-classification

I am a beginner in SVM. In my project, I use SVM to classify texts. The dataset is laptop reviews, and I classify into two classes, "good review" and "bad review". I have done the training, testing and classification, but there are a few things that made me confused and I want to ask.

1. Below are two examples of the data in a SVM format that has been
   scaled to [-1,1]:

   ```
   1st -> 1:-0.648936 2:-0.641171 3:-0.62963 4:-0.576841 5:-1 6:-1 7:-0.894737 8:-1 9:-0.225806 10:-0.641026 11:-0.481481 12:-1 13:-1 14:-0.5 15:-0.235294 16:-0.882353

   2nd -> 1:-0.457447 2:-0.668316 3:-0.111111 4:-0.386705 5:-1 6:-1 7:-0.578947 8:-1 9:0.0967742 10:-0.25641 11:-0.24183 12:0.333333 13:0.333333 14:-0.5 15:-0.230769 16:-0.884615
   ```

   The first produces a score 5.4750172361043 while the second produces
   0.99999999999985. I wonder why? I think, if I look at the data above, the second instance has a better value than the first one.
   And if I look at the original text data review, I think that the
   second instance has a "better" category of review than the first. So
   why does the output score not the same as I expected?
2. Is it normal that the output of SVM results above yield tremendous
   value, even more than -1 and 1? The whole result from the all
   datasets have the minimum SVM score of -4.5085001691845 and maximum
   of 7.1355405169311. I'm not so sure, but I think the result usually
   ranges between -1 and 1. Is there something wrong?
3. What should I do to get the results as you all might consider a
   normal? I mean, a good instance of the category of the reviews have
   a value between 0 and 1 or little more(like 1.135645), while the bad
   reviews have a value of about 0 to -1 (or like -1.0573545)

just additional information to my question:

- I use the SVM solver library from website phpir.com (Ian Barber)
- Parameter C and gamma that I use are still the default one, and I haven't done cross-validation
- I include a few examples of what is the good reviews or bad reviews in here: http://pastebin.com/cqDK7WA6

please help me, I'm really a beginner at this, maybe I did not understand the basic SVM concept, so I need your explanation, and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Normally SVM tries to find a decision function for separating the data of one class from the data of another one. The prediction is returning the distance to this decision function. So the bigger, the more sure the data is in the class; and the sign is above or below the decision function, which is the 0 level. For better understanding, just see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the decision values go from -5 to 7 isn't itself a problem. The only thing the SVM solver optimizes is the sign of the decision value. The svm considers that the datapoint that gives 5.47 from the same class as the one that gives 0.99.

Some suggestions:

- The real problem I see with what you're doing is that you're not
  searching for a good value of C and gamma. In not doing so you can be
  getting arbitrarily bad results. It would be important to know how well your classifier performs overall with previously unseen data, and to compare with and without a good C and gamma.
- It seems you're using an RBF kernel, and that seems reasonable. However many applications in natural language processing and sentiment analysis have reported better results with linear kernels.

Here is another question which has a checklist of things to verify when using SVMs:
[Supprt Vector Machine works in matlab, doesn't work in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670101/supprt-vector-machine-works-in-matlab-doesnt-work-in-c)

Comment: Thanks for the reply carlos. "The only thing the SVM solver optimizes is the sign of the decision value" Yes I know that, but what I'm trying to accomplish here is I made search engine and SVM score is one of the ranking factor,so review with better score will have higher position in the search result. Thats why I asked the first question,though both results are positive (and in same class),I expected the second instance would have the better score. Can you help me regarding of the purpose that I want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Actually some researches have been conducted in this direction. The output value of each SVM classifier can be mapped from [−∞;∞] to [0;1] mainly by platt's scaling or Isotonic Regression. Detailed can be found in this paper: [Predicting Good Probabilities With Supervised Learning, In Proc. Int. Conf. on Machine Learning (**ICML**) 2005, pp 625--632](http://machinelearning.org/proceedings/icml2005/papers/079_GoodProbabilities_NiculescuMizilCaruana.pdf).

Comment: Fixed link to paper: https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~alexn/papers/calibration.icml05.crc.rev3.pdf